# How can I compare nls parameters across groups in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like this

| iu | sample | obs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5625 | s | 0.312 |
| 1.5625 | s | 0.302 |
| 3.125 | s | 0.335 |
| 3.125 | s | 0.333 |
| 6.25 | s | 0.423 |
| 6.25 | s | 0.391 |
| 12.5 | s | 0.562 |
| 12.5 | s | 0.56 |
| 25 | s | 0.84 |
| 25 | s | 0.843 |
| 50 | s | 1.202 |
| 50 | s | 1.185 |
| 100 | s | 1.408 |
| 100 | s | 1.338 |
| 200 | s | 1.42 |
| 200 | s | 1.37 |
| 1.5625 | t | 0.317 |
| 1.5625 | t | 0.313 |
| 3.125 | t | 0.345 |
| 3.125 | t | 0.343 |
| 6.25 | t | 0.413 |
| 6.25 | t | 0.404 |
| 12.5 | t | 0.577 |
| 12.5 | t | 0.557 |
| 25 | t | 0.863 |
| 25 | t | 0.862 |
| 50 | t | 1.22 |
| 50 | t | 1.197 |
| 100 | t | 1.395 |
| 100 | t | 1.364 |
| 200 | t | 1.425 |
| 200 | t | 1.415 |

I want to use R to recreate SAS code below. I believe this SAS code means a nonlinear fit is performed for each subsets, where three parameters are the same and one parameter is different.

```
proc nlin data＝assay;
　model obs＝D＋(A－D)/(1＋(iu/((cs∗(sample＝“S”)
＋Ct∗(sample＝“T”))))∗∗(B));
　parms　D=1　B=1　Cs=1　Ct=1 A=1;
run;
```

So I write something like this then get

```
nlm_1 <- nls(obs ~ (a - d) / (1 + (iu / c[sample]) ^ b) + d, data = csf_1, start = list(a = 0.3, b = 1.8, c = c(25, 25), d = 1.4))
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) :
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

But without`[sample]`, the model can be calculated

```
nlm_1 <- nls(obs ~ (a - d) / (1 + (iu / c) ^ b) + d, data = csf_1, start = list(a = 0.3, b = 1.8, c = c(25), d = 1.4))
summary(nlm_1)
Formula: obs ~ (a - d)/(1 + (iu/c)^b) + d

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
a  0.31590    0.00824   38.34   <2e-16 ***
b  1.83368    0.06962   26.34   <2e-16 ***
c 25.58422    0.55494   46.10   <2e-16 ***
d  1.44777    0.01171  123.63   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:
0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.02049 on 28 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 4
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.721e-06
```

I don't get it, could some one tell me what's wrong with my code, and how can I achieve my goal with R? Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to use `sample` which is categorical as a index based on the code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akrun. After I converting `csf_1$sample` to factor, I finally get what I wanted.

```
csf_1[, 2] <- as.factor(c(rep("s", 16), rep("t", 16)))
nlm_1 <- nls(obs ~ (a - d) / (1 + (iu / c[sample]) ^ b) + d, data = csf_1, start = list(a = 0.3, b = 1.8, c = c(25, 25), d = 1.4))
summary(nlm_1)
Formula: obs ~ (a - d)/(1 + (iu/c[sample])^b) + d

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
a   0.315874   0.008102   38.99   <2e-16 ***
b   1.833303   0.068432   26.79   <2e-16 ***
c1 26.075317   0.656779   39.70   <2e-16 ***
c2 25.114050   0.632787   39.69   <2e-16 ***
d   1.447901   0.011518  125.71   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:
0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.02015 on 27 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 4
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.225e-06
```